# WebPack enable access to classes static members

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, global-variables

I am using WebPack with my TypeScript project.

I have several classes that have static members, *e.g.*:

```
class Human {
   public static DEFAULT_AGE: number = 20;
}
```

This class is imported by other files. I want to be able to change this variable in my browser's console like: `window.Human.DEFAULT_AGE = 30`, but the `Human` class is encapsulated and not visible in the global scope.

What can I add to the WebPack config to make this class globally accessible after the build process (in the browser). Note that I have multiple such classes, and I want a WebPack config solution, not just setting `global.Human = Human`, if it is possible.

I tried adding

```
output: {
  library: 'someName'
}
```

It does expose the `someName` namespace, but it is just an empty `esModule`.

Comment: I think you might need to export `Human` from the entry point of your project in order to make it available as `someName.Human`.